# Largest micro sd card

Tags: sd-card, memory

What is the largest micro sd card that the Raspberry Pi 3 can handle? I have a 64 gb card that works flawlessly, but would like to try something larger.

Comment: Quite related http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36/whats-the-maximum-sd-card-size-that-the-raspberry-pi-will-accept-do-larger-car Check the elinux-link. They keep a long list of working sd cards including size, make, and model

Comment: I think the ext4 limit is 4 exabytes and you can't get an SDCard that big. 256GB is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung 128GB MicroSD XC Evo Class 10 UHS-1 TF MicroSDHC TransFlash High Speed Memory Card MB-MP128DA that works just fine. Formatting to fat-dos was imperative. I only run octopi at this time but will be adding dietpi soon.