# Which (currently) compatible SD Cards have wear levelling?

Tags: sd-card, compatibility, durability

This question asks [Which SD cards are compatible?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/5/68)

[This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/502/68) describes the advantages of getting an SD card with wear levelling to extend the life of the card.

How can I find out which of the currently compatible SD cards have wear levelling?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A similar question as this one was asked over at Electronics.SE ([see here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27619/is-it-true-that-a-sd-mmc-card-does-wear-levelling-with-its-own-controller)) a couple months ago.  After doing a bit of snooping, it looks like probably the best way to find the card that is right for you is to select a small-subset of cards that you'd potentially like to purchase and then search the web for wear-leveling specs for each one.

As an aside, this information is useful to everyone.  If someone reading this both agrees and is active at the official Wiki site, it might be worth updating the [verified SD card hardware page](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards), laying it out as a table, and adding a field that delineates the known state of Wear Leveling for each specific card.

Comment: This is probably the best answer possible.