# Do I need to buy an SD card with an OS preloaded on it?

Tags: operating-systems, sd-card, purchasing

I finally got accepted to place a pre-order, and one option to "add" is the OS on the SD card preloaded. Is this needed, or can I download the OS elsewhere? Could I just put on my own version of Linux instead?

Comment: The main thing is that you need an SD card of 2GB or more and that the SD card is [compatible](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5/which-sd-cards-are-compatible/11#11) if you intend to use your own SD card

Comment: Good to know... I can get the Kingston cards :) I'll be happy I think. It should ship in 12 weeks apparently

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will need an SD Card with a Pi compatible operating system on it. Several options are available from the [official Raspberry Pi downloads](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads).

You may not need to buy one. Assuming you already have a compatible 4GB or larger SD Card and reader/writer you can create your own and save a few dollars. Directions for creating your own card can be found in [How do I install an OS image onto an SD card?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/931/86).